How to conect to VPN using azure data factory linked service
I have a client who don't want to install the SHIR in their SQL Server, so the client give me acess to a VPN connection and this informations:

IP
SQL Port
Username
Password

Is there anything I can do to connect in their server using the linked service of ADF?

To connect to an on-premises SQL Server using ADF without installing a Self-hosted Integration Runtime (SHIR), follow the steps provided in the procedure below:

Set up a private link service in the Azure portal that connects to the on-premises SQL Server.

Create an integration runtime with a virtual network configuration as shown below:




Go to the Azure Data Factory manage tab and create a new private endpoint by clicking the "New" option. Select the private link service option and choose your private link service name from the list and add <FQDN> of your on-premises SQL Server. Click on "Create" as shown below:



Create a sql server linked service with the required details as shown below:


For more information, refer to the MS document.
